# How to redirect a page to another domain, when the whole domain already redirects?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set a page to redirect to the same page on another domain. So I have

`https://domain1.com/pagetoredirect`

And I want it to point to

`https://domain2.com/pagetoredirect`

However, the whole of domain1.com is already redirecting to a specific page on domain2.com.

This is the setup in my conf file for the domain in `sites_enabled`.

```
map $http_host $new {
    ~^(www\.)?domain2.com 1;
    ~^(www\.)?domain3.com 2;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name ~^(www\.)?domain1.com$ ~^(www\.)?domain2.com$ ~^(www\.)?domain3.com$;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle2.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/[DOMAIN].key;

    if ($new = '1') {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.domain1.com/currentredirect;
    }

    if ($new = '2') {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.domain1.com/currentredirect;
    }

    return 302 https://www.domain1.com$request_uri;
}
```

I've tried adding an additional redirect for the specific page I want to repoint, using the following format:

```
rewrite ^(/pagetoredirect/) https://www.domain1.com/pagetoredirect;
```

I was hoping this would take precedence over the domain level redirect, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Location` blocks have a precedence depending on their specificity - more specific path will be matched first:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name .domain1.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle2.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain1.key;

    location / {
      return 301 https://www.domain2.com/currentredirect;
    }

    location /pagetoredirect {
      return 302 https://www.domain2.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Turns out the issue was that the domain wasn't even reaching my server - I hadn't realised that it had been pointed to a separate server with the same main redirect set up on there. So obviously none of my changes were doing anything.

Goes to show, always check the simple stuff first!

I'm marking your answer correct anyway, even though it turned out my problem was something different from the question.